# Multimap how to return all values from a key

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Multimaps can have multiple values how would I be able to return all the values from a key if it contains multiple values.

```
Multimap<String, String> wordcount = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

---

```
wordcount.put("1", "Dog");
wordcount.put("1", "Dog2");
wordcount.put("1", "Dog3");
```

---

So you can see above I gave my Multimap key "1" the following values "Dog", "Dog2" & "Dog3" how would I be able to print out all the dogs?

**Extra Questions**
How would I be able to check if a key contains multiple values of the same string for that specific key? Also how would I be able to return the amount of "same" strings it contains. It should return **3** because I specified the value **3** times with the same value so it should return **3**.

```
wordcount.put("1", "Dog");
wordcount.put("1", "Dog");
wordcount.put("1", "Dog");
```

Comment: the answer is in the Javadoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do `wordcount.get("1")` it will return a List containing `Dog1, Dog2, Dog3`

For your extra question: I think you have to do `wordcount.get("1")` to get the List object and iterate through the list object if you want to use an `ArrayListMultimap` instance.

Alternatively, you may want to checkout `Multiset<String>` that keeps track of number of occurrences of your input Strings. In this case you can use `Map<String, Multiset<String>>` instead of `ArrayListMultimap` instance to avoid iterating the returned list.

But `Multiset<?>` is a set so it does not iterate in the order you put the values.

Answer (score 2):

The [`get`](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#get(K)) method returns a list of values for a given key. You could just rely on the returned `List`'s `toString()`:

```
System.out.println(wordcount.get("1"));
```

Or just iterate over them and print each one separately:

```
for (String s : wordcount.get("1")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Or join all the values in that list to a single string somehow, e.g., by using a [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on(",").join(wordcount.get("1"))
```

Comment: How would I be able to store the same value over and over again for that key?